# how to split a long text from database to show it as different paragraphs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, field

I have fields like **text** ,**image**, in my table database i am using **SQLServer2008**.
I am displaying the text in my view page ,But the whole text was displaying at a time with continuous wordings, i just want to split them and show them as paragraphs.

I have used the following snippet

```
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Font-Names="Estrangelo Edessa" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Estrangelo Edessa">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div id="categorytextdata">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblcategorytext" runat="server" CssClass="categorytextdata" Text='<%# Eval(FixParagraph("CategoryText")) %>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Estrangelo Edessa" Width="5px" />
                    <ItemStyle Font-Names="Estrangelo Edessa" Width="5px" Wrap="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Need help.

Regards,

Comment: Does the text contain anything that can be interpreted as a new paragraph? Where should it be split?

Comment: You should store text with a html format and then retrive it. So it will automatically format it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a character in your "text" data you can use to split the data into the different paragraphs?  If so you can use the "Split" function to separate the data into an array of Strings you can make into different paragraphs.